# Прикрепить текстовый файл, видео и аудио после оплаты товара в Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, acf

Подскажите может кто сталкивался, как добавить возможность прикреплять файлы текстовые , видео и аудио после оплаты услуги через woocommerce. Человек будет заказывать услугу по написанию текстов, оплачивает, получает статус ожидает выполнения и далее через определенное время получает к заказу файлы ( поля добавлю через ACF)

Статус товара меняется от оплачен, ожидает выполнения до оплачен, выполнен.

Comment: Создайте отдельную страницу, уберите её с индексации, добавте на неё всё что вам надо, по необходимости редиректите пользователя на данную страницу.

Comment: Зачем это делать через движок захламляя его одноразовым мусором? Высылай файл на мыло, в месенджер и тд. В крайнем случае размещаешь где-то в облаке под паролем и сообщаешь покупателю ссылку с паролем.

Comment: Каждый пользователь имеет свой заказ и редиректить не выйдет. Так как заказ привязан к пользователю и редиректить не выйдет, так как менеджер должен получить заказ получить оплату за заказ и выполнить заказ и результат прикрепить. Выслать на Email не выйдет потому что это не удобно по Email. Моя цель прикрепить к API и отправлять в бота . Следовательно нужно изменять статус с прикрепленными файлами.